# List of all the geographic scope in Plotly

Tags: plotly

I am trying to plot data on a map using `plotly.js`. I know that you can achieve a map of a country from:

```
layout = dict(
        title = '',
        geo = dict(
            scope='usa',
            ...
             )
```

Do we have a list of available scopes, i.e. different regions, some where? I have tried googling it but can't seem to find it. In the example they have 'africa' as well, but how about other places?

Answer (score 20):

From [documentation](https://plot.ly/python/reference/#layout-geo-scope) :

> scope (enumerated: "world" | "usa" | "europe" | "asia" | "africa" | "north america" | "south america" ) 
>   default: "world"

Comment: Is there any way to limit to one or a few US states? How can I get the map to show only one state? or maybe some kinda automatic zoom at the beginning..

Comment: if you add fig.update_geos(fitbounds="locations") it will zoom in to data that's present. See https://plotly.com/python/map-configuration/#automatic-zooming-or-bounds-fitting "Automatic Zooming or Bounds Fitting"

Answer (score 1):

You can use create_choropleth , please see documentation at https://plotly.com/python/county-choropleth/

Here's an example:

```
import plotly.figure_factory as ff
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


'''
 By default scope is set to ['USA']
which the API treats as identical to passing a list of all 50 state names:
['AK', 'AL', 'CA', ...]
'''
df_sample = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/minoritymajority.csv')
df_sample_r = df_sample[df_sample['STNAME'] == 'California']

values = df_sample_r['TOT_POP'].tolist()
fips = df_sample_r['FIPS'].tolist()

colorscale = [
    'rgb(193, 193, 193)',
    'rgb(239,239,239)',
    'rgb(195, 196, 222)',
    'rgb(144,148,194)',
    'rgb(101,104,168)',
    'rgb(65, 53, 132)'
]

fig = ff.create_choropleth(
    fips=fips, values=values, scope=['CA', 'AZ', 'Nevada', 'Oregon', ' Idaho'],
    binning_endpoints=[14348, 63983, 134827, 426762, 2081313], colorscale=colorscale,
    county_outline={'color': 'rgb(255,255,255)', 'width': 0.5}, round_legend_values=True,
    legend_title='Population by County', title='California and Nearby States'
)
fig.layout.template = None
fig.show()
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Good link, you should post an example here as Matt suggested