# Map of a country with plotly

Tags: python, dictionary, plotly

The aim of create a **map of a country with plotly**. I show you the code to make the map with dots from cities and I want to change it to regions:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure(go.Scattergeo())
fig.update_geos(
    visible=False, resolution=50, scope="Spain",
    showcountries=True, countrycolor="Black",
    showsubunits=True, subunitcolor="Blue"
)
fig.update_layout(height=300, margin={"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0})
fig.show()
```

In the **scope** we have by default: *"world" | "usa" | "europe" | "asia" | "africa" | "north america" | "south america"*. How to **implement** those who are not in the scope? For example Spain.

Comment: the scopes are defined  only to `"world" | "usa" | "europe" | "asia" | "africa" | "north america" | "south america"`. As per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39106223/list-of-all-the-geographic-scope-in-plotly you could consider using choropleth map or consider using latitude and longitude

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- using **mapbox** instead of **geos**
- you can add layers to **mapbox** scatter
- have sourced cities and boundary geometries to demonstrate

```
import requests
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

# get Spain municipal boundaries
res = requests.get(
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/codeforgermany/click_that_hood/main/public/data/spain-provinces.geojson"
)

# get some cities in Spain
df = (
    pd.json_normalize(
        requests.get(
            "https://opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/6996f03a1b364dbab4008d99380370ed_0.geojson"
        ).json()["features"]
    )
    .loc[
        lambda d: d["properties.CNTRY_NAME"].eq("Spain"),
        ["properties.CITY_NAME", "geometry.coordinates"],
    ]
    .assign(
        lon=lambda d: d["geometry.coordinates"].apply(lambda v: v[0]),
        lat=lambda d: d["geometry.coordinates"].apply(lambda v: v[1]),
    )
)

# scatter the cities and add layer that shows municiple boundary
px.scatter_mapbox(df, lat="lat", lon="lon", hover_name="properties.CITY_NAME").update_layout(
    mapbox={
        "style": "carto-positron",
        "zoom": 3.5,
        "layers": [
            {
                "source": res.json(),
                "type": "line",
                "color": "green",
                "line": {"width": 1},
            }
        ],
    }
)
```

[image]

Comment: Can you tell me how to make the map instead of dots in the cities to be the whole regions the elements of the df. I want to add info about regions, not cities. Thanks you in advance!

Comment: that means you want a Choropleth instead of a scatter.  same geometry can be used and it becomes simpler if you use **geopandas**. happy to answer as another SO question if further input helps